# Can only enumerate once over IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Given is the following code (a xUnit test):

```cs
[Fact]
public void SetFilePathTest()
{
    // Arrange
    IBlobRepository blobRepository = null;
    IEnumerable<Photo> photos = new List<Photo>() 
    {
        new Photo()
        {
            File = "1.jpg"
        },
        new Photo()
        {
            File = "1.jpg"
        }
    };

    IEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob> blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>()
    {
        new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://blabla.net/media/photos/1.jpg")),
        new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://blabla.net/media/photos/2.jpg"))
    };

    // Act
    photos = blobRepository.SetFilePath2(photos, blobs);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(2, photos.Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, photos.Count());
}
```

Here is the `SetFilePath2` method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> SetFilePath2<T>(this IBlobRepository blobRepository, IEnumerable<T> entities, IEnumerable<CloudBlockBlob> blobs) where T : BlobEntityBase
{
    var firstBlob = blobs.FirstOrDefault();

    if (firstBlob is null == false)
    {
        var prefixLength = firstBlob.Parent.Prefix.Length;
        return entities
            .Join(blobs, x => x.File, y => y.Name.Substring(prefixLength), (entity, blob) => (entity, blob))
            .Select(x =>
            {
                x.entity.File = x.blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                return x.entity;
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I assert 2 times the very same thing. But only the first assert succeeds. When I step through with the debugger then I can only enumerate the collection once. So at the second `Assert` it yields no items back.

Can anyone explain me why that happens? I really don't see any problem with this code than explains this behavior.

Comment: Just curious would it behave the same if you change it to `blobRepository.SetFilePath2(photos.ToList(), blobs.ToList())`? or `blobRepository.SetFilePath2(photos.ToList(), blobs.ToList()).ToList()`?

Comment: `x.entity.File = x.blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;` -- you're modifying your collection while iterating over it. No wonder it's different the second time around.

Comment: I don't modify the collection. I modify the entity in the collection.

Comment: Yes, you modify the entity in such a way that the join fails the second time it's done. It joins on `entity.File` matching `blob.Name.Substring(prefixLength)`, but then you change `entity.File` to be `blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri`, so of course it will no longer match `blob.Name.Substring(prefixLength)`. Do not write `Select` methods with side-effects.

Comment: Ah true.You are absolutly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `.Count()`  you basically call 
`blobRepository.SetFilePath2(photos, blobs).Count()` and you modify the entity while using `Select`.I would recommend using `new` in the `Select` statement if you don't mean to alter the original value. That's why you get different results.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that "*you modify the entity*" specifically refers to `x.entity.File = x.blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: Actually, this is not true. It would be if `SetFilePath2` contained `yield return` statements, but it doesn't. It's the `entities.Join...` that's effectively executed again

Comment: @canton7 I've added the detail. Thanks for your constructive comments